# Automatically link identifiers in a code listing

Tags: hyperref, listings

I have some code listings (using the `listings` environment or the `lstinline` macro from the `listings` package) where I'd like to link all the identifiers defined in the present document to their definition. I only care about PDF output via pdflatex.

I'm satisfied with the indexing infrastructure that I already have, where I manually indicate where each identifier is defined, and I can manually link an occurrence of an identifier to its definition. For example (vastly simplified for the purpose of this question) I can write `\DefinedHere{foo}` to create an index entry and a hyperref target, and `\LinkDefinition{foo}` to typeset `foo` and link it to the hyperref target.

My question here is how to **make the `listings` infrastructure invoke `\LinkDefinition` *automatically*** (or some similar macro with a different syntax), either for all identifiers or for a predefined list of identifiers, so that each identifier is hyperlinked to the manually-defined target in the PDF.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=flexible}

\newcommand{\DefinedHere}[1]{\hypertarget{def.#1}{}}
\newcommand{\LinkToDefinition}[1]{\hyperlink{def.#1}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{Yin}

\begin{alltt}
def \LinkToDefinition{yin} = not \LinkToDefinition{yang}
\end{alltt}
\begin{lstlisting}
def yin = not yang
\end{lstlisting}

\newpage
\section{Yang}
\hypertarget{def.yang}{}
\begin{alltt}
def \LinkToDefinition{yang} = not \LinkToDefinition{yin}
\end{alltt}
\begin{lstlisting}
def yang = not yin
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The `alltt` sections illustrate the manual use of `\LinkToDefinition`. (If I was doing this manually, I might not index the occurrence in the definition itself, i.e. I wouldn't have `def yin` link to the definition of `yin`, but I don't care if that happens: .) I want to use `listings` package and achieve the same links as in the `alltt` examples, automatically, without having to add annotations to each listing.

I thought of adding something like this in my preamble:

```
\lstset{emph={yin,yang},emphstyle={\LinkToDefinition}}
```

but the `emphstyle` key expects a state-changing command, it doesn't take the word as an argument. Or

```
\lstset{index={yin,yang},indexstyle={\LinkToDefinition}}
```

but that typesets the identifier twice, because the argument of the `indexstyle` isn't expected to typeset the word. I can change `\LinkToDefinition` to typeset nothing, but that creates a zero-width link, instead of linking the word. Is there a way to combine the two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `literate` inside your `lstset`:

```
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=flexible,
        literate={yin}{\LinkToDefinition{yin}}{4}{yang}{\LinkToDefinition{yang}}{5},
        }
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=flexible,
        literate={yin}{\LinkToDefinition{yin}}{4}{yang}{\LinkToDefinition{yang}}{5},
        }

\newcommand{\DefinedHere}[1]{\hypertarget{def.#1}{}}
\newcommand{\LinkToDefinition}[1]{\hyperlink{def.#1}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{Yin}
\DefinedHere{yin}
\begin{lstlisting}
def yin = not yang
\end{lstlisting}

\newpage
\section{Yang}
\DefinedHere{yang}
\begin{lstlisting}
def yang = not yin
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Gilles Sorry, I've misunderstood the question. Is it now OK?

Comment: Aha, now that looks good. Is there a way to pass the text as the argument to the key value, so that I don't have to define a `literate` class for each identifier? Not a big hurdle, I suppose, it shouldn't matter with modern memory sizes.

Comment: @Gilles Not that I know....